# LocationManager minDistance settings issue

Tags: android, locationmanager

[I'm aware this is a duplicate to a question asked back in 2010 but that question never really got an answer]

I'm converting some of my Windows Phone apps to Android.  The apps all revolve around movement tracking.  In WP7 the location watcher has a "MovementThreshold" property that sets how much movement is necessary for the GPS to trigger a movement event.  Typically we want a lower threshold when walking and a higher one when in a jet airplane.  It can be throttled with code like this that changes it every time we get movement if the speed changes.

```
        if (mph < 7) watcher.MovementThreshold = 5;
            else if (mph < 15) watcher.MovementThreshold = 20;
            else if (mph < 30) watcher.MovementThreshold = 100;
            else if (mph < 50) watcher.MovementThreshold = 400;
            else if (mph < 100) watcher.MovementThreshold = 800;
            else if (mph < 120) watcher.MovementThreshold = 1200;
            else if (mph < 200) watcher.MovementThreshold = 2400;
            else if (mph < 400) watcher.MovementThreshold = 4800;
            else watcher.MovementThreshold = 9000;
```

Currently in my Android version of my app I make the following call one time when my location service starts...
locMgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locLstnr);

That 3rd parameter is minDistance (now set to zero) which sounds very much like MovementThreshold in WP7.

My first question is: Can I throttle minDistance in my Android app the same way I throttle MovementThreshold in my WP7 app?
My second question is: What kind of call would be most efficient to do the throtting?  - would I just repeat the above requestLocationUpdates call changing the minDistance parameter?
Thanks, Gary

Answer (score 0):

> Can I throttle minDistance in my Android app the same way I throttle MovementThreshold in my WP7 app?

IMHO, not really. Speed varies, and so you would need continuous GPS fixes to determine the speed so that you could adjust the throttling, which would defeat the throttling. In particular, when the jet plane lands, it will be some time before you ever find that out, because you are waiting for the user to travel a few km on foot (or car) first.

Of course, you would need that in WP7 too, and so I have no idea how you are pulling it off there.

Personally, I'd do that filtering myself, rather than use `minDistance` for it.

> What kind of call would be most efficient to do the throtting? - would I just repeat the above requestLocationUpdates call changing the minDistance parameter?

In principle, yes. However, quoting the documentation:

> The minDistance parameter can also be used to control the frequency of location updates. If it is greater than 0 then the location provider will only send your application an update when the location has changed by at least minDistance meters, AND at least minTime milliseconds have passed. However it is more difficult for location providers to save power using the minDistance parameter, so minTime should be the primary tool to conserving battery life.

(note that the documentation comments here regarding `minTime` are only really relevant for newer versions of Android; Android 1.x/2.x used `minTime` as a hint, not a filter)

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way is to throttle is based on time.  The docs have already been quoted in another answer, but it should be obvious that the device has to take distance measurements and filter them before getting to you to compute a distance threshold, whereas a time threshold allows the device to avoid taking location measurements.

I would encourage you to use a fixed time for polling, thus only needing to set the updates up once.  Ask yourself this question -- "How quickly does my app need to know about a change in distance (any distance)?"  If you can put a single number on it (1 sec, 100sec, whatever), use that as your update time.  You can use minDistance, too, if you want to avoid extra calls to your callback function.

Note that your thresholds are already in "time". You are computing a speed (mph) and you have a distance threshold (meters, I assume, since "MovementThreshold" in WP7 is in meters), you can easily compute the time it would take to move the distance in your threshold (distance/speed and account of the change in units) and use that number as your minTime because you know any measurement prior to the time should not be greater than your distance threshold unless the device has changed speed.  This gives you the sliding scale you are looking for, but using the more efficient minTime.

In the event of a change of speed, your polling time will be off until you get your first read at the new speed.  I suspect this does not matter to you, because if detecting these changes at a high resolution was important, you'd probably already be polling based on time instead of distance.